# Line alignment bug with user names and comments

Tags: bug, design

There seems to be a bug in the comments where if the username wraps to the next line and ends up underneath a word that contains characters like 'g' it will overlap those characters see:

[image]

The image is from a comment on [this answer.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/51355/87926)

I am using Windows 10 and Internet Explorer version 11.212.10586.0

Note, reproduced on this question, in chrome 50 on linux:

[image]

This still appears to be a problem:

[image]

Comment: Still readable, in my opinion. The alternative would look odd at best.

Comment: @Mast so the alternative of seeing all of the text would be odd?

Comment: @Quill See the update

Comment: @Simon Forsberg : It may be a little late to thank you, but your answer really lead me to the right direction. Since I was a beginner, I know laugh at this question on the words like don't suggest pdo, don't suggest prepared statements. Thanks man, you gave me the hurting truth at the right time.

Comment: @Quill also see my above comment which replicates the issue

Comment: Cool, reproduced on this question.... will edit the question with the reproduce ;-)

Comment: Repro on Chrome 52 & OS X El Capitan

Comment: @TheLethalCoder His edit makes the issue clearer though. The alternative I was hinting at was to increase the amount of room between the last and single-last line. That wouldn't look good.

Comment: @Mast My comment was a reference to the meme and you could always just increase the line spacing for all lines and not just one of them so keeping it consistent.

Comment: That would definitely decrease readability in my opinion. Is this issue bound to Code Review or can you reproduce it on other SE sites as well? I'm aware of the memes, but they shouldn't trump clarity.

Comment: @Mast Well I think so too but I don't like having words cut off and I will have to check and get back to you on that one. And I agree my comment was a joke and not to be taken seriously at all.

Comment: @Mast - this is a real issue, and should be fixed..... and, TheLethalCoder, I sincerely apologise for the lack of freehand circles, but, you should know that when I do them, I do them well, and I would hate to upstage your already elegant ones.

Comment: @rolfl Well thanks for that I will strive to one day do them as good as yours.

Comment: @Mast I haven't been able to see this on other sites, although I haven't looked that much

Comment: (Just a bunch of HNQs) but it doesn't happen on [electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/233316#comment507015_233316), [programmers](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/317966#comment674075_317966), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37133191#comment61810942_37133814) or [beta sites](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41417#comment117630_41418). I think it's just us.